# Dirichlet distribution vs Multinomial distribution?

Tags: multinomial-distribution, dirichlet-distribution

Both Dirichlet and multinomial distributions are distributions over vectors, and both Dirichlet and multinomial distributions are constrained so that all of the elements of these vectors sum to a constant value.

Can somebody explain in simple words (and maybe with an example)in-detailed differences between Dirichlet and multinomial distributions?

> **Does Dirichlet distribution serves the same purpose as a multinomial distribution?**
>
> **What are the advantages/disadvantages of using Dirichlet over multinomial distributions?**
>
> **What makes the Dirichlet distribution different from a multinomial distribution?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Multinomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution) is a *discrete*, multivariate distribution for $k$ variables $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_k$ where each $x_i \in \{0,1,\dots,n\}$ and $\sum_{i=1}^k x_i = n$. [Dirichlet distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution) is a *continuous*, multivariate distribution for $k$ variables $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_k$ where each $x_i \in (0,1)$ and $\sum_{i=1}^k x_i = 1$. In the first case, the support of the distribution is limited to a finite number of values, while in the second case, to the *infinite* number of values that fall into the unit interval are within the support.

> Does Dirichlet distribution serves the same purpose as a multinomial
>   distribution?

No. Multinomial is a distribution for counts, while Dirichlet is usually used as a [distribution over probabilities](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/244917/what-exactly-is-the-alpha-in-the-dirichlet-distribution/244946#244946).

> What are the advantages/disadvantages of using Dirichlet over
>   multinomial distributions?

They are different things, and as you can learn from the [Can a Multinomial(1/n, ..., 1/n) be characterized as a discretized Dirichlet(1, .., 1)?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/145705/can-a-multinomial1-n-1-n-be-characterized-as-a-discretized-dirichlet1) thread, they behave differently in higher dimensions. You would almost never use them exchangeably.

The exception is that in some cases, you might want to use a continuous distribution to *approximate* the discrete distribution, e.g. as you can approximate binomial (for large $n$), or Poisson distribution (for large $\lambda$) with Gaussian.

> What makes the Dirichlet distribution different from a multinomial
>   distribution?

They are continuous vs discrete distributions.

Answer (score 2):

A first difference is that multinomial distribution $\mathcal{M}(N, \mathbf{p})$ is discrete (it generalises binomial disrtibution) whereas Dirichlet distribution is continuous (it generalizes Beta distribution).

But if you were to make $N$ go to infinity in order to get an approximately continuous outcome, then the marginal distributions of components of a multinomial random variables will become gaussian, which has a different shape than Dirichlet distribution.

Dirichlet is commonly used as a prior on a probability vector, since it is the conjugate prior of the multinomial distribution.